# Startfile in Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I've just switched operating systems from Windows 10 to Mac OSX Sierra, and I've started using Sierra to do Python programming. What I used to do was open and write to a file, and then use os.startfile to automatically display everything that was written to it. Now that I've switched to Mac, opening and writing to a file is going okay (although I'm still figuring out how to have the files be saved to the Desktop) but os.startfile doesn't work. I've searched thoroughly for an equivalent to this, but nothing I've found seems to fit what I need. I'm using Python 3.x , and I think that the problem might be that all of the answers I have seen might be for Python 2. Could anyone give me a clear way of starting a file in the same way that os.startfile does and any information I might need about using it?

Comment: Maybe `os.system("open file.txt")` will work? BTW, `os.startfile` is _only_ available under Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly and did just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment by [ForceBru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354477/forcebru), `os.startfile` is only available on Windows.

For Mac, you should run `os.system("open some.file")`.

Answering as this question has no answer provided.